# Почему не удаляются параметры из адресной строки при использовании navigate в react по клику

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть на сайте сортировка по цене, при клике на кнопку 'дешевле'

```
onClick={() => {
    if (location.search.includes('asc')) {
        fetchByParams('_sort', '');
        fetchByParams('_order', '');
    } else {
        fetchByParams('_sort', 'asc');
    }
}}
```

идут товары по возрастающей цене, через это

```
const fetchByParams = async (query, value) => {
  const search = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  if (value === 'All') {
    search.delete(query);
  } else if (value == false) {
    search.delete(query, value);
  } else if (query == '_sort') {
    search.set(query, 'price');
    search.set('_order', value);
  } else {
    search.set(query, value);
  }
  const url = `${location.pathname}?${search.toString()}`;
  navigate(url);
};
```

в адресной ссылке появляется **'?_sort=price&_order=asc'** и нужно чтобы при повторном нажатии на кнопку с адресной ссылки это убиралось, но при повторном нажатии остается **'_sort=price'** а **'_order=asc'** удаляется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы из одного блока вызываете `fetchByParams` 2 раза. В каждый вызов передаете разные данные.
Однако вы не учитываете **асинхронность**.

> Если вы позовете ребенка дважды, он к вам 2 раза не придет!

Вы вызываете в одной группе {}

```
fetchByParams('_sort', '');
fetchByParams('_order', '');
```

Однако в функции вы смотрите на текущий **location.search**, который не успевает измениться.

**Что происходит:**

Ваш `location.search` равен **_sort=price&_order=asc**
Первый вызов функции удаляет **_sort** и передает в **navigate** остаток, т.е. **_order=asc**
Вызывается второй раз функция, однако ваш **location.search** по прежнему имеет значение **_sort=price&_order=asc**
Функция отрабатывает и передает в `navigate` **_sort=price**

**Результат:** вы видите в адресной строке **?_sort=price**

Один из вариантов - закостыльте вашу функцию `fetchByParams` где будете сразу убирать 2 параметра из адресной строки, как то вот так к примеру:

```
if (value == 'clear') {
  search.delete('_order');
  search.delete('_sort');
}
```

или, если надо полностью очистить от всего, попробовать вот так

```
if (value == 'clear') {
  search.forEach((val, key) => {
    search.delete(key)
  })
}
```

Решение остается за вами, как более правильно поправить данное поведение для вашего проекта